# excel vba - iterate through specific sheets in range

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to iterate through a list of sheets where the list is determined by a Range.
If I hard-code the list everything is fine.
what I'd like is to refer to a range that contains the sheet names (as it's variable).

```
Set mySheets = Sheets(Array("sheetOne", "sheetTwo", "sheetThree"))

With ActiveWorkbook
    For Each ws In mySheets
    'do the stuff here
    Next ws
End With
```

so something like this:

```
Set mySheets = Sheets(Range("A1:E1"))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how is this related to Google Sheets?

Comment: Please check : https://www.thesmallman.com/looping-through-worksheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
Sub MySub()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set mySheets = Sheets(removeEmpty(rangeToArray(Range("A1:E1"))))
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        MsgBox "An error has occurred. Check if all sheet names are correct and retry.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    With ActiveWorkbook
        For Each ws In mySheets
        'do the stuff here
        Next ws
    End With
End Sub

'This will transpose a Range into an Array()
Function rangeToArray(rng As Range) As Variant
    rangeToArray = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng))
End Function

'This will remove empty values and duplicates
Function removeEmpty(arr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim result As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim element As Variant

    For Each element In arr
        If element <> "" And Not result.Exists(element) Then
            result.Add element, Nothing
        End If
    Next

    removeEmpty = result.Keys
End Function
```

This will load dynamically `Sheets` contained in your `Range`.

#### Edit

- Added `Function` `removeEmpty(...)` to remove empty values and duplicates.

> **Note**: the `Function` `rangeToArray()` is needed to return data in `Array()` format.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Louis this is great. Do you know how to deal with a range that has blanks? e.g. if I set the range to "A1:F1" but F1 is blank? Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! The fastest method is to cycle through all of them and remove the empty elements. I'll edit the code with an Example.

Comment: I'm getting err "ActiveX component cant create object". Do I need to add a Reference?

Comment: With Late Binding it's not necessary, but try to add `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` and see if it works for you. On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: I already added the DLL. Err is on "set Result = CreateObject...." result = Nothing

Comment: With reference `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` added, try to use the updated code which uses early binding.

Comment: now errors with "subscript out of range" on "Set mySheets"

Comment: Ok, now it's working. That means that one or more of the sheet names in your range does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would provide this solution, which does load the sheetnames into an array:
Notice that you have to transpose the Data if the values are ordered horizontal.

```
Public Sub test()
Dim mySheet As Variant
Dim sheet As Variant

mySheet = Application.Transpose(Tabelle1.Range("A1:E1").Value) 'load your Values into an Array, of course the range can also be dynamic

For Each sheet In mySheet
    Debug.Print sheet 'print the sheet names, just for explaining purposes
    'it may be necessary to use CStr(sheet) if you want to refer to a sheet like Thisworkbook.Worksheets(CStr(sheet))
    'Do something
Next sheet

Erase mySheet 'delete the Array out of memory
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I demonstrate the code below which does what you want using an animated gif (click for better detail)

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub iterateSheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet, shName As String, i As Integer
i = 0
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    shName = sh.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0)
    Worksheets(shName).Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Font.Color = vbRed
    i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do like this:

```
Sub DoThat()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("A1:E1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If Worksheets(cell.Value2) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox cell.Value2 & " is not a sheet name in " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & " workbook"
        Else
            With Worksheets(cell.Value2)
                'do the stuff here
                Debug.Print .Name
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

or the other way around:

```
Sub DoThatTheOtherWayAround()
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(sht.Name, Range("A1:E1"), 0)) Then
            'do the stuff here
            Debug.Print sht.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

but in this latter case, you wouldn't be advised in case of any A1:E1 value not corresponding to actual sheet name